# Exercise of conditional and converse clarification

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I have this exercise in logic and discrete mathematics:

*It's a common error to confuse the following statements:

1. If $A$, then $B$.
2. If $B$, then $A$.

Describe two conditions $A$ and $B$ such as the statement 1. be true, but the statement 2. be false.*

I have made this solution:

1. If $x, y \in \mathbb{N}$, and $x$, $y$ are even numbers, then $x*y$ is an even number.

which is true.

and

2. If $x*y$ is an even number, then $x$ and $y$ are even numbers.

this is *false* because the product of two natural numbers, which both are not even numbers, can produce an even number; for example: $3 * 2$.

Is correct my solution?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to make "If $B$, then $A$" false is if $B$ is true yet $A$ is false.

So you can take $B$ to be $2+2=4$ and $A$ to be $0=1$.

You then only need to verify that

> If $0=1$ then $2+2=4$.

---

Involving $x$ and $y$ seems to complicate matters unnecessarily, and

> If $xy$ is an even number, then [$x,y\in \mathbb N$, and] $x$ and $y$ are even numbers

is not reliably false -- for example, it is true when $x=y=1$.